# Are there any WebRTC applications that can replace Google Hangouts and Skype?

Tags: video, skype-for-web, google-hangouts

WebRTC support is now available in Firefox and Chrome. Are there any actual applications, most likely - websites, that use it in a way that could replace the functionality of Google Hangouts and Skype?

I refer to (relatively) simple things:

- Conference for multiple people (say, at least up to ten) with video and audio
- Text chat (preferably persistent)
- Privacy (the ability to limit a conference to certain accounts or domains)
- Public broadcasting (like Live Hangout, which broadcasts to YouTube; of course, it doesn't have to be YouTube)
- Screen-sharing (at least read-only, though being able to click a partner's screen would be a nice bonus)

Though WebRTC sounds like a very hot technology, it's surprisingly hard to find applications that provide the above features in a robust way. Of course, it's possible that I didn't search well.

Comment: you can try signalrtc.com

Answer (score 3):

I built http://OpenTokRTC.com to show people multi-party video chat functionality. It eventually replaced skype and google hangouts for me and my friends. Its open sourced and free, so feel free to take it for a spin!

Unfortunately, it doesn't have all of the features you require (like screen-sharing), but it nailed everything else. Hope it helps!

Comment: Very cool app! It seems like you did this for OpenTOK? Do you have any API limits on that app, i.e. will it continue working even during a busy month?

Comment: Yup! it will continue working during a busy month :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [videolink2.me](http://videolink2.me)? It supports multi-user video calls (even without registration), has chat and allows to protect video conference with password.

Answer (score 0):

Give [skipti.co](http://skipti.co) a shot. A great tool for online conferencing.

Comment: Are you in anyway affiliated with the site and could you provide some more details about how it compares to Google Hangouts and Skype.

Comment: Well, as for skype, skipti offers a much better video quality, free group video chat, the ability to doodle and the fact that its browser powered and thus requires no downloading of software.

Comment: As for hangouts, with Skipti you don't need to have a google account, and also you don't need to email an invatation, as you can just all enter the same room with the name you chose beforehand. Moreover, you get better call quality and enjoy not having to install any plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Bistri](https://bistri.com), [vLine](https://vline.com), [Talky](https://talky.io) or [Browser Meeting](http://browsermeeting.com).

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at Tringgr.com which has video conference, audio only conference, group and private text chats, file transfer and high video quality.

Comment: If you are affiliated with the site, please disclose that information in your answer.